# Return value in Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, php-7.2, laravel-5.7

I'm using Vue 2 in Laravel 5.7, and in a Vue component I have the following inside a `v-for` loop:

```
<p v-html="getFacebookObjectInteractions(activities.id)"></p>
```

... which is where `activities.id` comes from, and that calls:

```
getFacebookObjectInteractions: function (object_id) {

    var self = this;

    var promiseMessages = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        self.getFacebookObjectComments(object_id, function (commentCount) {
            resolve(commentCount + " comments");
        });
    });

    // ... other methods go here.

    return Promise.all([
        promiseMessages, promiseLikes, promiseShares
    ]).then(function(messages) {
        var message = [];
        message.push(messages);
        var messageString = "Engagement " + message.join(", ") + ".";
        console.log(messageString);
        return messageString;
    });

}
```

I need the last `return` to send the result of the `.join()` to `v-html` but all I'm getting is `{}` instead.

But `console.log(messageString);` spits out the correct string value:

> Engagement: 2 comments, 3 likes, 1 shares.

If I do:

```
var something = Promise.all(...
```

... I have to do a `.then()` on it to get at the value in the promise and I'm in the same situation that I started with.

Any ideas?

Comment: no clue about the framework, but if v-html does not support promises than you will have to think about it a different way....

Comment: Notice that `getFacebookObjectComments` (etc.) should not take a callback but rather return a promise itself.

Comment: @epascarello, is it possible to get the value _outside_ of the promise in `getFacebookObjectInteractions()` and return it from there?

Comment: Why you do not use await?

Comment: @SergioEscudero I've tried `await` in a multitude of different combinations but they either do nothing or give me a compile error.

Comment: @Bergi, do you have a code sample? I've tried similar approaches but they didn't work.

Comment: @WayneSmallman Changing that would just be a good promise coding practice, but it won't solve your problem of `v-html` not being able to handle promises.

Comment: @Bergi, I have no attachment to the promises — I need to get the values from these methods and combine them into a string.

Comment: @WayneSmallman You cannot get asynchronously produced values immediately, with or without promises. But when doing it asynchronously, you definitely should use promsies.

Comment: @Bergi, given that I've tried and failed with dozens of different approaches over the last 6 hours, it would be more helpful to me if you were to provide an explicit example.

Comment: @WayneSmallman As I said, I don't even have a working solution! I just suggested a totally unrelated improvement

Answer (score 0):

`getFacebookObjectInteractions` returns a promise object rather than the object you're expecting. That's why the html isn't showing up. You should set `v-html` to a data or computed property instead. Then once the component is mounted you can call `getFacebookObjectInteractions` which will eventually update that property, then Vue will re-render the component with the correct html.

Based on your code it's a little unclear where activities comes from, so you may need to restructure your code even further, but this should give you the basic idea.

So in your HTML:

`<p v-html="html"></p>`

Then in your Vue component

```
{
    data(){
        return { html : "" }
    }
    methods : {
        getFacebookObjectInteractions(object_id){
            // ...
            Promise.all(...).then( (messages) => {
                // ...
                // Update your reactive property
                this.html = messageString
            })
        }
    }
    // Called when the component is mounted
    mounted(){
       this.getFacebookObjectInteractions(activities.id)
    }
}
```

See here for a more in-depth example: https://medium.com/js-dojo/async-in-vuejs-part-2-45e81c836e38

Comment: That article doesn't include anything to do with computed properties, or handling multiple methods.

Comment: No the main idea is how you can use an asynchronous method, in this case `Promise.all` to update the state of your application. What your asynchronous method does isn't important, what is important is that you update a reactive property in your vue component.

Comment: That's the code I had to begin with, but I need to combine the results of three different methods into one string, thus the use of promises.

Comment: That's not what you have. Note how the p element's html is bound to a reactive property on your vue component rather than the result of `getFacebookObjectInteractions`. This way when you update that property from anywhere in your code, vue will put the html into your component almost like magic.

Comment: When I first started coding, I had what you had, but — as I said — it won't work with when combining the values from multiple methods. I'm not making updates to the `<p>` tag, nor would that work _because_ of `v-html`.

If I return a single value from `getFacebookObjectInteractions()` it works with no problems.

Comment: Also, `getFacebookObjectInteractions()` requires a value be passed to it.

Comment: I understand that it requires a value. That's why I suggested you restructure your code. I can't help you do that, because I don't have enough information to know what you're trying to accomplish. But the point stands that the only (vue) way to update the html inside that p tag after an asynchronous call is to set a reactive property. Perhaps you can help me understand what you're trying to do by making a small example of what you mean in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue)? I'd also like to see more of what you had before to see if and what mistake you might have made there.

Comment: It would take as long to write a demonstration as it did to write the original; what's there is 90% of the code, sans the `v-for` loop the wraps around the `<p>` tag. I need to combine the values returned by 3 different methods (which use Axios to request data via an API) into one string, and return it to `v-html`. I have no attachment to promises — whatever code does the job.